# What kind of reinforcement learning is MENACE?

Tags: machine-learning

The famous MENACE matchbox computer for playing tic-tac-toe, invented by Donald Mitchie, is an early example of a reinforcement learning algorithm. Here is a [description](http://brainwagon.org/2011/08/28/donald-michie-alan-turing-martin-gardner-and-tic-tac-toe/):

> ...an interesting machine for playing tic-tac-toe. It was made
>   entirely out of matchboxes, each one of which had a tic tac toe
>   position on the top. Inside was a collection of colored beads. Each
>   color specified a possible legal move for the position on top. The
>   idea was that you’d play a game by drawing these beads from the
>   appropriate box, and making the appropriate move. At the end of the
>   game, you’d remove the bead from the last box that sent you along the
>   losing path. Eventually, all the losing moves get removed, and the
>   machine plays perfect tic-tac-toe. Gardner showed how this same idea
>   could be used to create a matchbox computer to play hexapawn, a simple
>   game played with six pawns on a 3×3 board.

My question is: what kind of algorithm is this, in modern parlance? Is it policy iteration? Q-learning? Or sooething else? I am a bit new to the subject and can't figure it out for sure.

Comment: ... brute force?

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). I am not sure if your question is a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope than this site or for [stats.se].

Answer (score -1):

I found this question because I was searching for an answer to it myself...so take my answer on this with a grain of salt...but I believe that it's similar to policy gradients. In policy gradients you increase the probability of taking actions when you see a large reward which followed those actions...that seems to be the idea behind MENACE as well.